# background:url is not displayed properly

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck. I created an image and want it to be a background image accessed through CSS for the navigation menu with text placed over it in HTML.

Here is my CSS:

```
.menu_item {
    background:url(../images/menu_normal.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Quotation Form</title>
        <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head>
    <body>

            <ul>
                <li class = "menu_item"><a href="#">About</li>
                <li class = "menu_item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li class = "menu_item"><a href="#">For Translators</a></li>
                <li class = "menu_item"><a href="#">Free Quotation</a></li>
            </ul>

            <img src = "images/menu_normal.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the result: http://eximi.dreamhosters.com/turbolingvo/menu.html

I want the image to be displayed behind the menu items just like it is displayed in the `<img src...>` below it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Which browser are you using ?

Comment: Do you want the background for each menu item or one continuous background for the entire list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need something like:

```
.menu_item {
background: url("../images/menu_normal.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
float: left;
height: 53px;
line-height: 53px;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
width: 227px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to style your li element to adjust look

for example

```
.menuitem{
background:url(../images/menu_normal.png) no-repeat;
display: block;
height: 33px;
padding: 10px;
width: 207px;
}
```

this is just example, you can style it however you like as per requirement

Comment: No need for display:block; list items are already block elements anyway.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for clearing up, but overtime i has developed my approach that i manually write down display type, if i mean something it should be there. Rather than being worried about default display type. However i would like to know what issue it make if you assign display property even though there is default display property is available

Comment: You just make your stylesheet unnecessarily longer than it needs to be. If you do it for every element, you could be adding substantial unnecessary weight to the file.

Comment: Agree, nice to learn. This is going to improve my work quality

Answer (score 0):

Change the background to be on `ul` element and give the `ul` element the class menu.

**CSS**

```
.menu {background:url(../images/menu_normal.png) no-repeat; }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class='menu'>
 <li><a href="#">About</li>
 <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">For Translators</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Free Quotation</a></li>                  
</ul>
```

Comment: I didn't explain it clearly, I'm sorry - I need the image repeated behind each menu item.
I styled my li element as Tyssen and tejash suggested, and it worked.
But thank you very much anyway!